# task.result.count , Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I just wonder what the difference is between task.result.length and just using the property directly.

So I have this:

```
int count = 20000;
char charToconcatnate = '1';

Task<string> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ConcatChars(charToconcatnate, count));
Console.WriteLine("IN progress");
task.Wait();

Console.WriteLine("Completed");
Console.WriteLine("The length of the result is:" + task.Result.Length);
Console.Read();


public static string ConcatChars(char charToConcanate, int count)
{
    string concateneatedString = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        concateneatedString += charToConcanate;
    }           
    return concateneatedString;
}
```

But if I do it like this:

```
int count = 20000;
char charToconcatnate = '1';

Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ConcatChars(charToconcatnate, count));
Console.WriteLine("IN progress");
task.Wait();

Console.WriteLine("Completed");
Console.WriteLine("The length of the result is:" + count);
Console.Read();


public static string ConcatChars(char charToConcanate, int count)
{
    string concateneatedString = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        concateneatedString += charToConcanate;
    }           
    return concateneatedString;
}
```

The output is by both the same.

So what is the difference?

Comment: It is impossible to say without a [mcve] (i.e. knowing what `ConcatChars` does).

Comment: The short answer is that the second code block is meaningless. The output would be the same _regardless of what `ConcatChars` did_. The first code block is _actually checking the output of `ConcatChars`_. It would be like sending my kid to the shops and saying "buy 144 eggs" and then when they come back declaring I have 144 eggs _without looking at what he bought_.

Comment: I edited my question. Why still -1 then??? sorry, but is not how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`task.Result` is a string that's 20,000 characters long. So `task.Result.Length` returns `20000`.

`count` also returns `20000`. (It's what causes `task.Result` to be 20,000 characters long in the first place!)

Both outputs are the same because they get the same value (`20000`) for the string concatenation.